# ManagedObject attribute value is changed to unexpected value after I call save

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have an attribute `synced` of type Integer16 in my core-data model.  I am trying to set the value of synced to `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]`, when the value is synced with that on my server, just like I do on many of the other managed object subclasses I have in my app.  The problem is, that for this particular class, any time I call `[context save:]`, the value gets reset to `[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]`.

My suspicion was that I might have another instance of that object in my code somewhere that has synced set to NO, but I'm fairly certain that this is not the case.  Can anyone offer me some advice to help resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Why use an `Integer16` when you can just use `boolean`?

Comment: I don't know why I made that decision... there probably wasn't a good reason.  I dont think changing the type would fix the problem though.

Comment: Before you save have you confirmed that `synced` actually is set to `YES`

Comment: yes, i have.  i set to YES, logged, saved, and then logged it again.  The first log was YES, and the second was NO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of hard without any real code but things you could try:

Override the setter and place a break point so you can see when it is being called.

```
- (void)set<#Capitalized property name#>:(<#Property type#> *)value
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"<#Property name#>"];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:value forKey:@"<#Property name#>"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"<#Property name#>"];
}
```

OR try using KVO for the same purpose (see when the values being changed)

```
[theObject addObserver:theObserver forKeyPath:@"keyPath" options:0 context:nil];
```

---

Make sure you have not overridden `willSave` with anything that is changing the value.

---

Check it is definitely the same object that was saved/fetched?

Comment: you got it with the last suggestion -- i forgot that i was overriding willSave and changing the value of synced.  Thanks so much!